# Select Grandchild using CSS Attribute Selector

Tags: html, css

CSS I **can** tweak, HTML I **have to** work with.

```css
.first [class="tag"] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!--Entire width & height of page-->
<div class="first">
  <!--Only a portion of width & height of page-->
  <div class="second">
    <div class="tag">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the background color of the **first** class on each page containing the **tag** id. The CSS that I've created can only select the first child and not the grandchild as I need. Any suggestions? Prefer a CSS solution, but not necessary. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/11683)

Comment: You want to change the color of `.first` depending on whether it contains `.tag`? You simply can't.

Comment: Why would you even use an attribute selector here? They're both class attributes, not ids.

Answer (score 0):

I see now that there is no current CSS solution. Thanks guys.

https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/